# What kind of possessive pronouns are used after the preposition "mit"?

Tags: possessive-pronoun

> Das Mädchen isst mit *ihrem* Großvater.
>   Der Junge schwimmt mit *seinen* Freundinnen.

In these sentences what kind of poessessive pronouns are *ihrem* and *seinen*?

What about this case:

> Der Junge besucht *seinen* Großvater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with possessives in German, you need to look for three things: the gender and number of the possessor; the gender and number of the possessed; and the case of the possessed. Let’s start with your second sample sentence.

- Der Junge schwimmt mit seinen Freundinnen.

Since ‚Der Junge‘ is *m* *sg*, we need to use a form of ‚sein‘ (= his). More particularly, we need to use a *f* *pl* form, since ‚Freundinnen‘ is *f* *pl*. Finally, the preposition ‚mit‘ requires **Dat**. Thus, we need the *Dat* *pl* *f* of ‚sein‘ and that’s ‚seinen‘.

- Der junge besucht seinen Großvater.

As before, ‚Der Junge‘ is *m* *sg* and we need to use a form of ‚sein‘. Since ‚Großvater‘ is *m* *sg*, we need to use a *m* *sg* form. Now, ‚besitzen‘ requires **Acc**: *Wen* besucht er? Den Großvater. Thus, we need the *Acc* *sg* *m* of ‚sein‘ and that’s ‚seinen‘. That’s a bit confusing since ‚seinen‘ is also the *Dat* *f* *pl* of ‚sein‘, as we saw. Still, it’s correct.

- Das Mädchen isst mit ihrem Großvater.

This is where things get tricky: ‚Mächden‘ is technically neuter, and not feminine! So, strictly speaking, we’d need to use the possessive ‚sein‘ again (which is both *m* and *n*). However, since Mädchen are female, it’s now common to treat the noun as though it was *f*. Hence, the possessive ‚ihr‘ is used.
The rest is by now familiar: ‚Großvater‘ is *m* *sg* and ‚mit‘ requires **Dat**. Thus, we need the  *Dat* *sg* *m* of ‚ihr‘, which is ‚ihrem‘.

Comment: In the latter case, most native speakers would consider both *ihrem* and *seinem* correct.

Comment: @Janka The author/speaker might deliberately use "ihrem" to point out that the girl is already rather female (so almost a young woman), or "seinem" to point out that the girl can not be considered a female yet, e.g. she's just a small kid. Of course both pronouns are correct, but they will leave a slightly different impression of the girl in the readers/listeners mind.

Comment: Don't say that too loud, I was 10 times (15 times?) downvoted when I mentioned that another day.